# IntelliJ is not showing the projects properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is not exactly a programming question, however, I assume this is related. I use a MacBook Pro and after having an issue recently installed the `OS El Capitan`. Obviously, I had to install a quite a few software including the `IntelliJ`. When I open one of the projects, eventually, its shows like this,

[image]

I should mention there is an interruption during the time of initial opening and I still have all the files intact in the project.

What to do in this respect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to import a project as a maven project. When you will be selecting file or directory to import there you need to select the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your project is not properly recognized as a maven project.

1. Click on the maven window on the left panel.
2. Click the + button and select the pom.xml.

Comment: Where is the `Maven` window in the left panel?

Comment: Click on the command button twice and hold it, it should appears.